Can someone explain why this pops up when i hit control right-Click
I even search in the keymapping to make sure it was still mapped to extrude to cursor or add



You have some add-on that's doing this.

It looks as if that's being produced by an addon although that shortcut isn't used by the normal "3D Viewport Pie Menus" addon. Try typing 'pie' into the search field under Edit > Preferences > Addons and see what is shown there.

You probably accidentally switch to a different preset / theme like Maya
